# ImageView With Button inside

Tags: android, layout, imageview, profile

I want to do the imageView layout with the button to edit photo inside.

[image]

I think to put image as imageView background but i don´t know how to do the semicircle transparency and set the icon.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Now i have this.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:background="@color/blue_bar">
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@color/black"/>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/image"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_photo"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#B3ffffff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can i do the imageButtons background as a semicircular shape?

Comment: You could use a FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to make a CompoundView.
1) I would make a RelativeLayout with the imageview width and height set to match_parent, then a button with alignBottom set to true.

2) Then keep using your button normally in your Activity.

3) You can go fancier and use a CompoundView extending ViewGroup and putting the functionality of the button.
Here is a tutorial for it:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: how can i do the background of the button?